# How to fix error running tsc index.ts with axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

I'm getting an error when I run `tsc index.ts` to compile typescript having axios imported.
I have typescript installed globally.
Created a clean directory and what I did was run `npm init -y`, npm install axios, then create my *index.ts* a import axios inside:

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

axios.get(url).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

When I run `tsc index.ts` to compile I get the following error:
[image]
Also installed the *tsconfig.json* with comand `tsc --init` but didn't change anything. Current configuration the default:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

If I run `ts-node index.ts` the *index.ts* is compiled without error.
How can I fix this error when running `tsc index.ts` to compile?

node version v18.17.1
npm version 10.4.0
typescript version 5.3.3
axios 1.6.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install TypeScript Node Types as a developer dependency.

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

#### Using TypeScript definition file

TypeScript to write code that uses external libraries like axios, you need to provide type information for those libraries. TypeScript uses type definition files (with a .d.ts extension) to understand the shapes and types of objects and functions provided by these libraries.

It will automatically to add axios.d.ts when you install `npm install axios`

But also axios need to install `@types/node` too.
The command `npm insatll --save-dev @types/node installs type definitions for the Node.js runtime.

The reason is that axios relies on certain **`Node.js-specific types and features`**

Node.js, and TypeScript needs to understand these to provide type checking.

Installing @types/node ensures that TypeScript has access to the necessary type definitions for Node.js-specific functionality.

##### Result

[image]